# For loop to set multiple onclick listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, button

I have nine buttons that I want to open up a overlay contact box but I can't create a working for loop to do what I want to do. Basically I want to avoid using this...

```
contactButton[0].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[1].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[2].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[3].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[4].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[5].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[6].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[7].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[8].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
contactButton[9].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
```

What is the best way to create a loop to help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < contactButton.length; i++) {
    contactButton[i].onclick = function(){overlay.style.display = "block";}
}
```